# How to modify an element in a list

Tags: string, list, python-3.x, for-loop

I have a list of string elements that i want to edit. i know which elements to edit only from an indexed list. I want to edit the elements and only add a specific adjustment to all the specific elements. How can i edit the elements in the list?

for example if i have

```
 Index=[2,5,6]
 Items=['Hello','world','this','is','bob','how','do','you','do','?']
```

i want to add a '\n' to the start of words so that when it prints it starts a new line. So the code would end up like

```
 Items=['Hello','world','\nthis','is','bob','\nhow','\ndo','you','do','?']
```

and it would print of like

```
Hello world

this is bob

how

do you do ?
```

Comment: What did you try? This looks like a straight-forward problem, so please at least show us your attempt.

Comment: i had   for q in range(0,sentences-1):
               count=count+words[q]
               almost.insert(count,'\n')
               count=count+1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in Index:
    Items[i] = "\n" + Items[i]
```

Note: In Python we usually write variables lowercase.

Answer (score -1):

Meow?
try this

```
index=[2, 5, 6]
item=['Hello', 'world', 'this', 'is', 'bob', 'how', 'do', 'you', 'do', '?']

for key in index:
    item[key] = '\n' + item[key] # put '/n' to item with determinate key in index

print (item)


for word in item:
    print (word + ' ', end="") #end="", don't '\n' after print, use ""
```

Result:

```
['Hello', 'world', '\nthis', 'is', 'bob', '\nhow', '\ndo', 'you', 'do', '?']
Hello world 
this is bob 
how 
do you do ?
```

Comment: Include a comment for why you give the answer you do. Explain the solution, and why it works / why it's better.